# Ajax post returning full html page as response

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, forms

The issue is as follows: whenever I post the form, I have a console log with the response which is a full HTML page rather than a simple message.

When I put url in ajax - console output error 404.
image: https://ibb.co/Qb422sC

```
$("#admin_form").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        data: $("#admin_form").serialize(),
        success: function(response) {
            if(response == "1")
            {
                alert("WELCOME ADMIN");
            }
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
});
```

```php
if(isset($_POST["admin_name"]))
{
echo "1";
}
```

Without url: https://ibb.co/7GVR3Q2

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: I only want to to get echo "1" in response not full html page

Comment: put `exit();` after `echo "1";` and check onces ,also if still you get that response .. make separate `php` page and put your `code` there. also don't forget to give `url` of that page in `ajax` call .

Comment: exit(); not working and php must be on this page

Comment: Put `php` code at top of your file i.e : `<?php if(isset($_POST["admin_name"]))
{
echo "1"; exit();
} ?>` and add `dataType: 'text'` in ajax call .

Comment: YES, Thanks this solved the problem!